# Django Models Tree Structure

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Is there a possibility to create Tree-Like Structures in Django.

I want to create a model called Workbook which contains different Worksheets.
I also want to be able to switch in between the worksheets and edit them.

The structure should be similar to excel.

I already looked into django-mptt, but I am not sure if i should familiarize myself with it, since I am a beginner

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Define a Foreign Key relationship:

```
class Workbook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Worksheet(models.Model):
    workbook = models.ForeignKey(Workbook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='worksheets')
    text = models.TextField()
```

This way each workbook might have multiple worksheets.
You can get all workbook's worksheets with:
`Workbook.objects.get(pk=<id of specific book>).worksheets.all()`

Comment: yes I did it this way, but in this way it is like creating two seperate models. What i want to do is to get one big model which contains smaller models on the same website, as i am creating worksheets on the administration site.